# using vue cli or webpack to build individual vue components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vue-cli, vue-cli-3

Say I have the following components folder:

```
components/
  Component1.vue
  Component2.vue
  Component3.vue
```

Is there a way to build each of the individual components into this type of distribution:

```
dist/
  Component1/
    index.html
    script.js
    styles.css
  Component2/
    index.html
    script.js
    styles.css
  Component3/
    index.html
    script.js
    styles.css
```

Basically I need to build a components library. I'd like to use vue to build them, but the thing that's consuming components library needs `html` file, `css` file and `js` file for each component instead of a vue SFC.

Using `vue-cli-service build` i know I'm able to pass in a different entry instead of `src/App.vue`, but the distro doesn't seem to work when I run it on a simple server. Are there any gotchas with changing the entry point and corresponding build configurations? Also, if there any solid references for how to tackle this problem I'm trying to solve, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried having a "library" build target? You can create a "library" then import that component(s) as needed in other Vue projects. https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/build-targets.html#library

Comment: i don't need to consume it in another vue app. I need to be able to consume static files generated by vue cli or webpack

Comment: I'm pretty sure I understand what you're saying -- but not sure how to accomplish it.  This would have to be in your webpack config - I have 'chunked' my vendor files individually before, but not Vue files like you are asking... maybe this can help you? [This is how I chunked my vendor files individually...](https://github.com/oze4/ipvue_original/blob/master/build/webpack.config.prod.js#L35-L50)

Comment: I suppose you could also try something like this, even though they are not separate pages..? I'm really interested if you solve this... seems like it should be way easier to accomplish.. https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#pages

Comment: If you lazy load your components like the first screenshot in the link below, this appears to split your files - but not like you are wanting, I don't think... This is such a pain!! https://imgur.com/a/ZYL2VWc You can browse the project here: https://github.com/oze4/ipvue/tree/master/docs/assets/js

Comment: i had a coworker recommend different entry points for the various build processes, a 1 to 1 for entry point to component. Going to navigate those waters for a bit